# Placement of 3D object not working the SECOND time my button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I programmatically added a button to my ARSCNView and added a function that's called whenever it's tapped. The function creates and place a 3D object. The button works perfectly the first time it's pressed, but the second time onwards it does not place my object.

Here's my code:

private var button = UIButton()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    button.setTitle("Body", for: button.state)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 25, width: 100, height: 25)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        self.createPlaneNode()
}

func createPlaneNode() {
    //Create a new scene with our 3D object in it
    print("Hi")
    //This prints everytime the button is pressed, I checked.


    let object = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/manbody.obj")
    let node = SCNNode()
    let nodeArray = object!.rootNode.childNodes

    for childNode in nodeArray {
        node.addChildNode(childNode)
    }

    guard let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
        return
    }
    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translation.columns.3.z = -0.1 // Translate 10 cm in front of the camera
    node.simdTransform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

    // SCNPlanes are vertically oriented in their local coordinate space.
    // Rotate it to match the horizontal orientation of the ARPlaneAnchor.

    node.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work the second time, check the poly count. ;)

However, you cannot see the result of subsequent calls as you keep putting the object at the same place.

You set a new position here correctly:

```
node.simdTransform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
```

But then you overwrite the transform on the next line:

```
node.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Note that `node.simdTransform` and `node.transform` are just different "views" of the same thing.

Change the node's pivot to apply the rotation instead, or multiply the transform instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Ugh yes thank you I just figured it out myself.

Follow up question: How do i rotate my node without placing it in the same position everytime?

Comment: @Jharden13 That is explained on the last line in my answer, let me know if it is somehow unclear.

Comment: Oh okay. Do I just set my node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi/ 2, 1, 0, 0)?

Comment: Yes. That way SceneKit will multiply it with the transform under the hood to get the final thing.